# How do I build Boost.Build before compiling boost using MinGW on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, boost, build, mingw, boost-build

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 and trying to set up a C++ dev environment. I installed MinGW, and that *seems* to be working properly on its own. Next, I need to install boost... it seems the only good option is to compile from source. (I don't see any official Windows binaries. I found several unofficial ones, but they tend to be several version behind current and it isn't clear that they're being maintained.)

So I download the tarball, extract it, open the MSYS shell from MinGW, go to tools/build/v2 and run bootstrap.sh - this fails, and bootstrap.log reads as follows:

```
###
### Using 'gcc' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
gcc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathsys.c pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c class.c cwd.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c
builtins.c:34:23: fatal error: sys/wait.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
execunix.c:20:26: fatal error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
fileunix.c:96:17: fatal error: ar.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

As best I can figure, I don't *have* those files. (I don't see them in my MinGW install anywhere...) So next I tried bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=mingw (which seems to be a "supported" option...) and it seems to get a little farther before giving a different error. Here is the bootstrap.log from that run:

```
###
### Using 'mingw' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
gcc -DNT -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathsys.c pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c class.c cwd.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execnt.c filent.c
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=mingw --toolset-root= clean
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
...updated 1 target...
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=mingw --toolset-root=
don't know how to make modules/set.c
don't know how to make modules/path.c
don't know how to make modules/regex.c
don't know how to make modules/property-set.c
don't know how to make modules/sequence.c
don't know how to make modules/order.c
...found 126 targets...
...updating 1 target...
...can't find 6 targets...
...can't make 2 targets...
failed to write command file!
```

I tried to go looking for these files (or where they're supposed to be anyhow) and I can't even find a modules directory anywhere... so I'm pretty stumped on this error. I can't even tell for sure whether these are generated source files that it is supposed to build but can't for some reason, or are files that are supposed to already exist and it just can't find them (and in the latter case, whether they're supposed to be included with the boost source or supposed to already be on my system somewhere).

Does anyone know how to fix this error and get boost built? (or at least get Boost.Build built, which is supposed to be the first step towards building boost...?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use MSYS shell. Make sure g++.exe is on path, and via cmd.exe run

`d:\Libraries\Boost\boost_1_53_0>bootstrap.bat gcc`

This should produce b2.exe which can then be used to build (parts of) Boost.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. The trick is just to do it in the regular Windows shell (or powershell) and no the MSYS shell... I did `bootstrap.bat mingw` actually, although both seem to work. I half suspect mingw is just an alias for gcc anyhow (but I haven't verified that). The following step is to run `b2` to build boost itself. What you do _that_ you need to specify gcc as the toolchain - it doesn't recognize mingw as a toolchain. That's running the build process for me right now, and everything seems to be working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since neither `bootstrap.bat mingw` nor `bootstrap.bat gcc` generate a correct `project-config.jam`, i.e. which does not contain `msvc`, I ended up changing manually `msvc` to `gcc` in `project-config.jam`. By the way, `mingw` didn't do the trick.

I could have a different behavior due to the first execution of `bootstrap` and `b2` commands which partially built boost libraries with msvc12 compiler.